# imagick converting pdf to jpg throws an error

Tags: php, imagick

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $int; $i++) {
    $im = new imagick();
    // $im->readimage($soubory."[".$i."]");
    $im->setResolution(300, 300);
    $im->readImage($soubory . "[" . $i . "]");
    $im->resampleImage(150, 150, imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);
    $im->resizeImage(512, 700, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $i = sprintf("%03s", $i);
    $im->writeImage('../pdf/publisher/' . $select . '/x-' . $i . '.jpg');
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();

    if ($i == 000) {
        $preview = '../pdf/publisher/' . $select . '/x-' . $i . '.jpg';
    }
}
```

If I have a file with size less than 4 MB it works perfectly. But some files do not upload. I don't know why.

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed `/data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/pdf/9.pdf': No such file or directory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/611' in /data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/funkce.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/funkce.php(92): Imagick->readimage('/data/web/virtu...') #1 /data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/adm/includes/pdf_publisher.php(4): uploadpdf(NULL) #2 /data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/adm/includes/container.php(17): include('/data/web/virtu...') #3 /data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/adm/index.php(155): include('/data/web/virtu...') #4 {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/69845/virtual/www/domains/nabytek-novydomov.cz/funkce.php on line 92

Comment: Have you tried increasing [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) for your script?

Comment: Does you script has an access to the file ?

Comment: Script have access to the file. if he did not approach does not work in any case. And i try  ini_set("memory_limit","30M"); but result is the same

Comment: btw you probably don't want to set `Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED` it's behaviour is undefined.

Comment: i delete Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the example - that is a very large pdf. Opening it with ImageMagick doesn't give an error for me, however the PDF isn't rendered correctly either.

ImageMagick actually renders PDFs by delegating the rendering to the GhostScript program. I think you would be better off calling GhostScript directly, to render the PDFs to PNGs and then be able manipulate the images once they are in sensible format e.g.

To generate PNG files of all the pages, you should be able to call Ghostscript from the command line, so long as it is setup in your path, as:

```
gs \
-sDEVICE=png16m \
-o %03d.png \
-r300 \
casopis.pdf
```

Or just select certain pages.

```
gs \
-sDEVICE=png16m \
-o %03d.png \
-dFirstPage=10 \
-dLastPage=13 \
-r300 \
casopis.pdf
```

If you really want Jpeg output, you can configure that as the [output device](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eghost/doc/AFPL/8.00/Devices.htm#JFIF).

I haven't been able to replicate the error you are seeing. It's entirely possible that it's due to either ImageMagick or GhostScript being unable to create some temporary files, or just running out of memory.

Regardless, the answer is to call ghostscript directly, rather than have to jump through two layers of abstraction to process very large files.

---

Explicit instructions for how to invoke GS from the command line

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Go to the directory where the PDF is.
3. Run the command from

If you wanted to invoke it from PHP, you would need to use [exec](https://www.php.net/function.exec) or one of the other functions for calling stuff on the command line.

Comment: Max upload on my server is 32M. it must be a different problem.

Comment: What about the setting on the webserver? The error message "No such file or directory" strongly indicates the file wasn't uploaded correctly.

Comment: This error is only in some pdf but some pdf upload correctly. If it was a mistake to upload any file fails but some file can upload

Comment: [link](http://nabytek-novydomov.cz/casopis-dobroty-podzim2013-web-177.pdf) this pdf doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand what is your code it's php or what? PS: Sorry for my stupidity :D

Comment: I still dont understand how i can do it..:/