# imagick - pdf to jpg quality problems

Tags: ghostscript, imagick

I am trying to upload and convert pdf to jpeg image, i am using ghostscript with imagick and php. the problem is the quality of jpeg is not really satisfying.

this is my settings and what i use

exec('convert -density 400  -colorspace sRGB "'.$pdf_path.'[0]"  -resize 842  -quality 100 "'.$save_path.'.jpg"');

which settings should i use?

as you can see the pictures are dark, the text is not clear. this is the url of the original pdf "
http://icebergfeeds.co.uk/admin/images/magazine-content/54085a9d5a03d.pdf"  and here is the 
example result ,
[image]

Comment: http://icebergfeeds.co.uk/admin/images/magazine-content/540736661ba41.pdf Error 404

Comment: sorry it was dynamic content, updated the url

Comment: Rendering it with the current version of Ghostscript looks fine to me. Of course I have no idea what the ImageMagick configuration means in terms of Ghostscript configuration.

Comment: Hi - sorry too busy to give real answers, but can you look at Ghostscript having a bug in text anti-aliasing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085550/php-imagick-pdf-conversion-text-aliasing/23144243#23144243 which may be easier to investigate by calling ghostscript directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676548/imagick-converting-pdf-to-jpg-throws-an-error/23679893#23679893

Answer (score 5):

For me im using ghostscript to extract images in JPEG with high quality, this is my script:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dAutoRotatePages=/None -o D:\temp\cover_thumb.jpg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -dJPEGQ=100 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r150 -dUseTrimBox D:\temp\pdfs\a.pdf -q
```

you can play with the quality using the parameter -r im my case its 150 but you can increase it for more better quality